# How to call a function only on the user's first login on React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to put an alert with an information that should only appear in the first login of each user in my app, how do I call this function only on the first access?

Comment: When user visit's the page for the first time set a cookie or use a local storage value, if the **cookie** or **storage value** is there you know it is his ***second*** login.

Comment: You mean on the _very first login ever_ or _the first time they logs in after installing the app_, using cookies can be useful, but if your case is the first one you have to validate that on your server/db first

Comment: @JoseVf I mean you might want to have a check for any user, it always check's if a cookie exists that's within **30 days**. If not we plant the cookie.

Comment: @Raymond I asked because on mobile apps the cookies don't persist if the user uninstall and reinstall the app, if you want to show _something_ on the **actual very first time** they access, the validation must be on the server side, **but** if you want to show it on the first time they access the app cookies will do the job

Comment: @JoseVf are you the OP on another account?

Comment: @Raymond I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55422518/how-to-call-a-function-only-on-the-users-first-login-on-react-native?noredirect=1#comment97564411_55422518). And reading all the comments, I think you though the question was for you, but actually was for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this depends on your policy. If you want to set it for after first login ever(don't care if she will login for first time on another devices) you should use a server call to set such flag on db. However, if you want to make it local to the device, yo may use storage i.e. [asyncstorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage)

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In response to my comment on using cookies or local storage.

Step 1: User visit's website.

Step 2: App checks if a cookie, database, or local storage (non-mobile) is present.

Step 3: If the special cookie name **is not** present we now set the cookie, and show the **first time** page. If **it is** present, we show the **visited** page.

> Android

You can possibly used a shared setting in the shared preferences. This is the same basic concept as checking for a document or item, it the preference isn't there it is the firs time.

> All

Generate a hash for a IP Address and store it in a database for a said user. Setup an API  endpoint for when user installs app it checks against this.

Comment: I don't know if you know, but React Native is for mobile applications, not for websites.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when I would set a `last_login` field for `User` table.

If that's `null`, it would be safe to assume that it's the first time the user logs in.